# float rounding problems in python

Tags: python

```
amount = 0.002638309660058967
price = 1392.18

lowest_ask = 1391.6

result = price*amount/lowest_ask

print(result)
```

The above code will print out:

```
0.002639409271731024
```

However when I perform the calculation here: http://web2.0calc.com/
It gives me: 0.0026394092717310237698

So obviously python is rounding up the result of this calculation....

My question is, how do you prevent python from rounding up result? i.e. I want result to be: 0.002639409271731023

Comment: Would https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html help?

Answer (score 2):

Python is using IEEE 64-bit floating point to do the calculations.  You can get it to print out as many digits as you want, but that later digits won't be meaningful since there is only so much that can be represented in 64-bits.

```
>>> print "{0:.30f}".format(result)
0.002639409271731024079349348099
```

If you want more digits of precision, then you won't be able to use the float type.  In that case you can use the decimal module, but the calculations will be much slower.

If you do go down the path of using the decimal module, then here's the code with the default 28 digits of precision:

```
from decimal import *
amount = Decimal('0.002638309660058967')
price = Decimal('1392.18')
lowest_ask = Decimal('1391.6')
result = price*amount/lowest_ask
print(result)

0.002639409271731023769804541535
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your example is related to small financial operations, the `decimal` module is a good choice (see previous answer). For scientific computation with high emphasis on speed, you could use some arbitrary-precision module like `gmpy`:

```
from gmpy import mpf
amount = mpf('0.002638309660058967')
price = mpf('1392.18')
lowest_ask = mpf('1391.6')
result = price*amount/lowest_ask
print(result)
```

0.0026394092717310237698

(of course you can use as many digits as wanted). For computing with a fixed amount of precision ~32 or ~64 decimal digits, the module [qd](https://github.com/baruchel/qd) is also a good choice.